# Porting Directshow filter to QuickTime

Tags: macos, directshow, quicktime

I have a DirectShow transformation filter that I need to port to Mac. The closest parallel I have found in the Apple docs is the quick-time video effect component as detailed starting page 64 in [this](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/QuickTime/Rm/EffectsTransitions/Effects/Effects.pdf) Apple developer's doc. However the document is dated 2009 and marked as 'legacy' which makes me worry that I might be missing something more current/relevant.

Can someone with more experience in the Apple space please point me in the right direction. I'm looking to build the correct kind of component to plugin a custom frame-by-frame pixel-by-pixel transformation process to a Mac video (post) processing pipe-line, ideally as a custom effect applied from within Avid or Adobe Premiere Pro.

Is a quick-time video effect component the way to go?

Thank you.